# Intel WiDi dual display support?

Tags: multiple-monitors, tv, hdtv

I'm looking forward to purchase [Intel WiDi](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/intel-wireless-display.html) adapter for my TV. But does WiDi support dual display? Meaning, not just translating my laptop screen to TV, but actually using both simultaneously, s.t. TV is used as a second display? To obtain result similar to [this setup](http://insighttechsolutions.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/11.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually called extended mode:
[image: Extended mode]

and, if I'm not mistaken, it is supported in windows 7 by default (Win+P shortcut). And Wi-Di seems to support it as well, as mentioned at [Intel Support](https://communities.intel.com/thread/37264).